# What is the difference between Tensorflow installation via source vs using pip?

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip

I'm want to run tensorflow on a very standard machine setup (windows 64 bit) and have read that tensorflow has greater performance if built from source as it is optimised for your system. When installing tensorflow via pip for why does pip not select the optimal build for your system?

Also if you did install via pip is there a way or being able to tell whether the optimal build has been installed, or is the only way of knowing that simply remembering how you installed it?

Comment: I recall getting the _"The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations"_ when not being built from source. See [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8037#issuecomment-283831398).

Answer (score 1):

Google has taken the position, that it is not reasonable to build TF for every possible instruction set out there. They only release generic builds for Linux, Mac and Windows. You must build from source if you want all the optimizations for your particular machine's instruction set.